# Insert image but keep getting error. Path validated

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, insert

[image]

I have tried to add an image with the code below, or see screenshot, it claims file name is not valid. But testfile above has all the same characters and works fine.  Please assist.

```
Private Sub InsertJPGs()
    For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    Dim Value As Variant
    Dim imageName As String
    
    
        originalLineText = singleLine.Range.Text
        lineText = singleLine.Range.Text
        If InStr(lineText, ".jpg") <> 0 Then
            singleLine.Range.Select
            rangeText = Left(singleLine.Range.Text, Len(singleLine.Range.Text) - 1)


            'rangeText = singleLine.Range.Text
            imageName = "D:\Downloads\ReportImages\" & rangeText
            'imageName = "D:\Downloads\ReportImages\PictureImportTest_ATTICSkylight#1#_img2.jpg"
            Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
             imageName, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        End If
        If InStr(lineText, "[[[IMAGE LIST]]]") <> 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next singleLine
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `imageName` when you get the error? Is it what you expect?

Comment: You suffer from [The Macro Recorder Curse](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/06/30/the-macro-recorder-curse/), break it! Don't show image of code, paste formatted text (read [ask])!

Comment: Try `Debug.Print imageName`after string concat (shown in immediate window) to see the path. Copy and paste result to explorer.exe navbar and see it fail to open the file;)

Comment: File name: "848477-773845_BEDROOMCloset#0#_img0.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is covering the most important line of code it is difficult to assess.

However, whatever the undeclared variable `singleLine` is supposed to be, it is likely that `singleLine.Range.Text` is terminated with either a paragraph mark or a line feed. So changing

```
rangeText = singleLine.Range.Text
```

to

`rangeText = Left(singleLine.Range.Text, Len(singleLine.Range.Text)-1)`

will probably solve the issue.

Comment: A hint to use [Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-) should be added!

Comment: I tried same issue... is what I think was happening also.  But tried-1 and-2 neither work

Comment: As singleLine represents a paragraph its Range.Text definitely includes the paragraph marker, which is a single character and needs to be removed. You will need to carefully check the rest of the text yourself to ensure that it does contain what you think it should.